# Javascript Promises in For Loops

Tags: javascript, loops, promise, ecmascript-6

I'm struggling to get the following Promise logic right:

I call a ReST API which returns an array of objects. I then need to loop through this array and start building a new array of objects with some of the data. This all works fine, so far.

Within the data I get from the API response, there are 2 id fields (in each object), for which I need to make subsequent API calls. When I get the data back from each of these calls, I add some more data to my new object. Only then, should the `For` loop continue.

I've tried using `Promises`, but for some reason the `For` loop continues, while the `Promise` is still busy. Any ideas?

Comment: Try using `.map()`, `Promise.all()` instead of `for` loop

Comment: Any of the standard itteration methods `for / for in / array.forEach / array.map` will continue because they are not asynchronous methods. Look into `Promise.all` to pass it an array of promises which it will resolve with when they all do. If your workflow can't work like look look into a recursive solution.

Comment: What's with the downvotes?

Answer (score -1):

I'd recommend using [bluebird](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird).

```
  var Promise = require('bluebird');

  // slow method that takes a second to return
  var asyncCall = (value) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      setTimeout(() => resolve(value), 1000);
    });
  }

  // things to iterate over
  var values = [1,2,3,4];

  // using Promise, iterate over the promises
  Promise.each(values, (value) => asyncCall(value).then(() => console.log(value)));

  // if you have some other promise library instead of bluebird, you
  // can manually implement it something like this.
  // please be careful with error handling
  function sequentialEach(values, cb) {
    if (values.length === 0) { return };
    try {
      var result = cb(values[0]);
      if (result && result.then) {
        return result.then(() => sequentialEach(values.slice(1), cb));
      } else {
        return sequentialEach(values.slice(1), cb);
      }
    } catch (e) {
      // assuming your library has .reject, you could alternatively
      // new Promise((resolve, reject) => reject(e))
      return Promise.reject(e);
    } 
  }
```